# Selectable text in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I would like to get a JTree instance, where I can select text in the node (for example: drag mouse from word "mouse" to the end of that sentence. I mean the change of the background color, that shows You what is selected, copy it to the clipboard and so on...).

I tries using JTextArea, JTextField and many more, but they always seems to be disabled. I cannot change this behaviour. Do you have any ideas how can I change that?

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JTree and described issue in your question, before that to read Oracle tutorial - How to use Trees (parts about Renderer and Editor)

Comment: Tree itself is a regular JTree. The only thing that I do is set renderer with 'JTree.setRenderer()'. My custom renderer is extending DefaultTreeCellRenderer. In 'getTreeCellRendererComponent' method oryginal super method is called, and after that I am taking text, background and foreground color from produced JLabel, assign it to JTextField and return my text field. Problem is, that is always seems to be disabled.

Comment: You might consider building your GUI in two parts: the left containing a selectable JTree, and the right containing a layout of the Object selected.  You could make your Object changes on the right side layout.  Something like this [Java Swing File Browser](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=637).